# TypeScript interfaces that are used to "new" objects

Tags: typescript

First, this question first arose after working with Three.js where I tried/trying to build interfaces for the library for my own sake.

Anyways, lets say we have the JS code:

```
var foo = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
```

In TypeScript you could represent the THREE object as:

```
interface IThreeJS {
    Vector3(x: number, y: number, z: number): any;
}

declare var THREE: IThreeJS;
```

However as you can see we have ': any' returning from Vector3.  If I create a IVector3 interface and try doing 'new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0): IVector3' we get a 'new expression on valid on constructors'.  Hence having to return 'any'

Right now the only alternative is to have the Vector3 object off of IThreeJS return 'any' and do:

```
var foo: IVector3 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
```

So, is there anyway to have my IThreeJS interface's Vector3 method have a constructor AND return an IVector3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare classes and modules too:

```
declare module THREE {
    export class Vector3 {
        constructor(x: number, y: number, z: number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aw, yes, If I were building the library from scratch this would be an appropriate solution.  I'm referring to creating an interface that sits ontop of an already pre-existing library that's done in JavaScript.  This is all to make using the JS Library easier within my TypeScript applications.

Comment: That is what Steve's code does. The `declare` keyword means "I'm describing an object implemented elsewhere"

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Vector3 {

  x: number;
  y: number;
  z: number;


  constructor(x, y , z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }

}
```

> const position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

#### Good luck